# Handling user specified icon resources with windows

Tags: windows, winapi

The documentation for WM_SETICON doesn't say anything about who is responsible for destroying icons. Does it happen when the window is destroyed or is the user supposed to do it after the window is destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a community addition on the WM_SETICON page saying this:

> The system does not make a copy of the icon. Do not destroy the icon before destroying the window.

What I usually do is the same I do for GDI objects within a Device Context: Always keep the old value in memory, restore it before destruction, and then delete mine.